# Problema no uso do Geocoder

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, localização

Senhores, boa noite.

Estou começando a programar em kotlin e estou com problemas no uso de localização com a ferramenta Geocoder.

Estou tentando pegar a localização e transformar e um texto visível para o usuário, porém esta caindo apenas na condição de valor nulo, retornando minha Toast. Poderiam me ajudar a achar onde esta o problema?
Já me certifiquei das liberações no Manifest e Gradle e a importação das mesmas na classe.

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    if (v.id == R.id.text_location) {
        getLastLocation()
    }
}
```

**Função para autorizar o uso de localização**

```
private fun getLastLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Solicitar permissões caso não estejam concedidas
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ),
            1001
        )
        return
    }
```

**Autorizado o uso, pego latitude e longitude**

```
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
    .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
        location?.let {
            val latitude = it.latitude
            val longitude = it.longitude
            geocoderHelper.getAddress(latitude, longitude)
        } ?: run {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Não foi possível obter a localização atual",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "Não foi possível obter os detalhes de localização",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }


    fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                " Não foi possível obter a localização atual",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
}

}
```

**Código que estou chamando para entregar a latitude e longitude.**

```
class GeocoderHelper (private val context: Context) {
    fun getAddress(latitude: Double, longitude: Double): Address? {
        val geocoder = Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault())
        try {
            val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)
            if (addresses!!.isNotEmpty()) {
                return addresses[0]
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

No código acima, sei que não estou anexando o valor de latitude e longitude a view em questão, porém a leitura fica caindo sempre na Toast.

Desde já, agradeço a atenção e qualquer dica será muito bem vinda.